# Power management system

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, battery-charging, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I would like to design a microcontroller based embedded system that is composed of the following subsustems:

1.Two sensors of 5V inputs.
2.One 12V DC motor controlled by a 12 V relay (ON/OFF).
3.One 12V Servo motor(PWM Controlled).
3.A battery charging system.
4.Load sharing system between a battery pack and the main power supply.

A simple block diagram of the system is shown below:
[image]

My concern is about the power management system composed of the Buck converter, the battery charging system and the 5V power supply.

1. How do I proceed to design a stable buck converter to supply a battery charger that may be another switching regulator, a 12V Relay and 12DC motor ?
2. What do you suggest for the 5V power supply module? Should I use a linear regulator and in that case there will be much power dissipated. Or should I use another buck converter IC ?

Any other suggestions concerning the optimasition of the system are welcome.

Comment: (1) Could you design a buck converter that powers a fixed load? What about one where the load varied a bit? When you say *stable buck* what do you actually mean? (2) How much heat do you think would be dissipated (given that anyone reading this question cannot possibly know based on the info you've supplied)?

Comment: Adding to @Andyaka questions.  a) Where's the 14V buck converter getting its energy from? (rectified mains or another battery)? b) How are you planning to implement a load sharing with two different voltage levels? Isn't load redundancy / backup management the term you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I have already designed a buck converter for a varying load (resistive load). But what bothers me here is the varying inductive load (The motors and the relay). So when I said, a stable buck converter, I meant a converter that will not oscillate, a converter with a fixed output voltage. How do I get a model of these three inductive loads, can anyone illustrate it by an example?

Comment: to@vtolentino, Yes I mean a redundancy/backup management system. when the main power is lost, the battery takes the role of a power supply to the system

Comment: to@vtolentino, Yes I mean a redundancy/backup management system. when the main power is lost, the battery takes the role of a power supply to the system